How to refer to offline copy of onnx.tar.gz file while calling chromadb collections.add
Im using python to connect to chromadb and from the chromadb.client when im using the  method collections.add, it is trying to download a file onnx.tar.gz from aws. External internet connections are blocked in our premisis. So i downloaded the file from allowed channels.
But now how to refer this file to collections.add method as it is still trying to download the file and fails
import chromadb
client = chromadb.Client()
collection = client.get_or_create_collection(name='test')
collection.add(documents=['ABCD'], metadatas=[{'id'},{'source':'xyz'}],ids=['id1'])

This collection.add is failing to collect onnx.tar.gz.
I copied the file onnx.tar.gz to project folder hoping that it will refer to it. But still it fails

The downloaded file is referred from the .cache folder of the windows. something like C:\Users<USER ID>.cache\chroma
Copy the downloaded file to that locationa
